# WCF Proxy Pool/Manager

Tags: wcf, client, pool

My application needs to comunicate with several external WCF services to satisfy requests from client applications. Being itself a WCF service, it must of course be able to process several simultaneous requests. That being, and since I will be acessing more than one service, I thought about grouping clients in the following manner:

```
public static class ClientManager
{
    private static readonly Service1Client _service1Client = new Service1Client();
    private static readonly Service2Client _service2Client = new Service2Client();
    ...

    public static Service1Client Service1DefaultClient { get { return _service1Client; } }
    public static Service2Client Service2DefaultClient { get { return _service2Client; } }
}
```

Then, from the remaining of the code, I would only need to execute

```
ClientManager.Service1DefaultClient.SomeMethod();
ClientManager.Service2DefaultClient.SomeMethod();
...
```

The idea is to create a central place to better manage WCF clients. However, I don't really know if this design is the most appropriate one for a service which will be issuing several requests at the same time to `Service1DefaultClient` and `Service2DefaultClient`. What do you suggest? Creating a more complex client pool with several proxies from each service to choose from?

Answer (score 3):

Having static client proxies doesn't look like a good idea to me.

- If ClientBase instance transitions to the Faulted state, it becomes unusable and you have to re-create it.
- If you have a stateful service, session lifetime will be the same as lifetime of a client proxy object, which is very long in your case.
- Depending on your binding settings, ClientBase [may serialize concurrent calls](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/95daa492-f4a2-474e-9772-7b10f9f5eda2/) made on the same proxy instance. In your case, this may strongly affect performance.
- I just don't see what problem does this solve.

Proxies are relatively lightweight because of the [ChannelFactory caching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx), so I would just create a new instance every time it is needed.